# How do I create a built-in demo regarding App Store Connect Guideline?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have a problem when pushing my iOS App to the App Store. I know this is not a coding issue.

I got rejected because of guideline 2.1 that the App Store wants to test full features of my app. There are parts of features that they are unable to reproduce (e.g. OTP code, product code ,etc).

What does it mean by providing built-in demo regarding the 2.1 guidelines? How can I make it?

> Added to 2.1: “If you are unable to provide a demo account due to
> legal or security obligations, you may include a built-in demo mode in
> lieu of a demo account with prior approval by Apple. Ensure the demo
> mode exhibits your app’s full features and functionality.”

Answer (score -2):

My apps never got rejected. You can use the form where you can put comments to the reviewer into how to create an OTP entry, for instance, like, use this seed, and provide the seed. Remember the QRcode are only a convenience to provide the seed. Try a seed like 123456 depending on the algorithm the length may vary. Just inform how they can view this feature working. It's very simple actually. I cannot see something that you cannot communicate previouslly to the reviewer... if was a network access, provide a temporary APIKEY or better, a demo account. You can always remove later.